# MVC pattern for multiple JButtons

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller

How should i implement an MVC controller with multiple JButtons on the view?

for example: i have a start button, stop button and many others as well.

I tried to do this for the start button and it works fine but then how do i implement it for a stop button trigger?

**Controller Code:**

```
public MVCAuctionController(Auction a, MVCAuctionView v) {
        auction = a;
        view = v;
        view.addProcessBidsListener(new ProcessBidsController());
        view.addStopProcessListener(new StopBidsController());
    }


    class ProcessBidsController  implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        { 
            view.disableProcessButton();
            Thread thread = new Thread (auction);
            thread.start();
        }

    }
```

addProcessBidsListener - is associated with the START/Process button,When i click on the button - the thread starts running and fills the JTextArea with data.

Now my Stop button should stop the thread. For this if i do something like this it doesnt actually stop the Thread:

```
class ProcessStartController  implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        { 
            if(e.getSource() == view.start){            
            view.disableStartButton();
            new Thread (rest).start();
            //thread.start();
            System.out.println("inside action performed of start button");
            view.kitchen.append("Orders to kitchen");
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == view.stop)
            {
                new Thread (rest).interrupt();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Looks like you've already got a somewhat decent set up started. What specifically has you confused?

Comment: addProcessBidsListener - is associated with the START/Process button,When i click on the button - the thread starts running and fills the JTextArea with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `Action` for each button, they are self contained controllers

See [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

You can then set up some kind of relationship between the Actions and the main controller should you need it, via some kind listener for example